# Call to function async from constructor is illegal

Tags: c#

Is it legal to call async method from constructor ?

```
public SettingsView()
{
   InitializeComponent();

    LoadData();
}

private async Task LoadData()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What does the compiler have to say about it?

Comment: Awaiting it is not permitted but firing off is legal.

Comment: Can you clarify the title of this question? That reads like a statement, and then you ask a question if it is legal.

Comment: The complier say there is a warning is ok or its better way? :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS4014)

Comment: Is legal or not?